# Google Play store - App rejected due to Mobiburn SDK

Tags: android, google-play

I upgraded APK on Play store but it got rejected with reason as

> APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY​ & Prominent disclosure
>
> Your app is uploading users' phone number, installed packages, and
> email account information information via Mobiburn SDK

On checking dependency graph of app, I couldn't find any evidence of Mobiburn SDK. Also verified none of any 3rd party lib used in app, have ever used Mobiburn.

Checked signed/unsigned APK by reverse engineering (APK analyzer). There are few .SO files packaged in APK when using 3rd party SDK(s) - Somehow reverse engineered .SO files too. But no evidence of Mobiburn SDK found in code.

Does anyone experience this issue earlier? or What else I can try to find evidence for Mobiburn. Appreciate help.

Comment: MobiBurn seems to be an app monetization service without ads. Have you updated any of your monetization libraries / code or anything to do with monetization in the last update? Dare I suggest creating a backup and removing code / SDKs and attempting to upload it as a different app until it goes through and you can figure out what the culprit was. Google probably has advanced detection algorithms and even if it's not in the dependency graph it possibly could be triggering on some code in your app or an SDK you're using. Most likely monetization-related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of 3rd party sdk/library used in application was extracting user's information without permission. It is then identified as Mobiburn SDK which was doing similar thing, However there are still no evidence of having Mobiburn SDK in our app though problem is resolved by including permission & prominent disclosure in app.

Answer (score 1):

I have had an update rejected before. I appealed and the appeal was accepted. It took a few days. You should have details about how to appeal in your email. But in case you don't, here is the link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals

Don't worry, if it is fine they will reinstate your app.

Comment: Yes, I have appealed already as I am sure no evidence of Mobileburn in code. Let's see.